# Highstocks update date in rangeSelector

Tags: highcharts

Does anyone know how to programmatically update the dates in the rangeSelector?

Here is a fiddle of my chart http://jsfiddle.net/ibike365/jneQh/1/

```
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
    // Create the chart
    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart : {
            renderTo : 'container'
        },

        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        title : {
            text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    },function(chart){




          console.log(chart.rangeSelector);



    });
});
```

I have a use case where I need to be able to set specific start and end dates for the selected range when I load the chart, but I'm not having much luck. When I inspect the chart.rangeSelector property in the console, I don't even see what to update.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out:

`chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(startDate.getTime(), endDate.getTime());`

Comment: Hi Charles,
Could you throw some light on how to use this statement? I am pretty new to Highstock chart. Thanks in advance.